# Getting errors "Missing ',' or '}'", "Unexpected token" and "got 'undefined'" for my JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

I have got some JSON-LD here and getting errors which I can't fathom out and you guys are the ones with the know how :)

Here's the errors I'm getting (code at bottom):

1. `Missing ',' or '}' in object declaration   (at the sameAs - line 7)`
2. When I check it on: http://json.parser.online.fr/

   I get the String parse:

   ```
   1 errorJS eval fails 
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 0
   ```
3. When I check it on: http://jsonlint.com/

   I get:

   ```
   Error: Parse error on line 1:
   < script type = 'app
   ^
   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
   ```

I don't understand why as it looks (to my untrained eye!) that the script type is what everyone uses?

```html
    <script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "schema dot org url",
  "@type": "JewelryStore",
  "name": "A.K. Campbell and Sons",
  "url": "company website jewellers url/”,
  "sameAs": [
    "youtube channel about url”, "google plus page url", "facebook url", "linkedin url", "twitter url"
  ],
  "logo": "photo url",
  "image": "image url",
  "description": "A.K. Campbell and Sons Jewellers of Kirkcaldy provides unique and bespoke gold, silver and diamond jewellery and jewellery services including valuations, pearl re-stringing and jewellery cleaning.",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "277 High Street",
    "addressLocality": "Kirkcaldy",
    "addressRegion": "Fife",
    "postalCode": "KY1 1JH",
    "addressCountry": "UK"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "56.11261",
    "longitude": "-3.15585"
  },
  "hasMap": "my map url - wasn't allowed to post it",
  "openingHours": "Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa 10:00-16:00",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "contactType": "customer service",
    "telephone": "+44 01592 264305"
  }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: _Aside:_ How are you coding this? These sort of errors look like you are perhaps hand coding in a WYSIWYG type editor, instead of a code editor?

Comment: You have the correct answer below but FYI your error in #3 is due to you pasting the script tag in there as well. You should have only put the JSON itself.

Answer (score 6):

You use `”` instead of `"` two times:

- Instead of

  ```json
  "url": "company website jewellers url/”,
  ```

  it has to be

  ```json
  "url": "company website jewellers url/",
  ```
- Instead of

  ```json
  "sameAs": [
      "youtube channel about url”, "google plus page url", "facebook url", "linkedin url", "twitter url"
  ],
  ```

  it has to be

  ```json
  "sameAs": [
      "youtube channel about url", "google plus page url", "facebook url", "linkedin url", "twitter url"
  ],
  ```